# How to use css & html to build 3 boxes stacking on top of each other

Tags: css, overlays

I am trying to code 3 boxes sequentially proportionate to each other using css.

Eg.: Box 1 is bigger and inside bix one is box 2 which is smaller but centered within box 1. and box 3 inside box 2 which is also proportionally centered within box 2. So sort of box 1 > box 2 > box 3. Someting like this...

But anytime i do it box 2 and 3 are not really centering the way i want them to.

**Code**:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="Box1">
        <div class="Box2">
            <div class="Box3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- End Of Center-Wrapper --->
</div>
<!--- End Of Wrapper --->
</body>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcquaye/mxtCs/

Comment: Here is the Link to my code pls... for some reason i couldnt put it in there  (http://jsfiddle.net/mcquaye/mxtCs/)

Comment: For the inner boxes add `margin:0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

add margin auto to box2 and box3

```
.box2{margin:auto;}
.box3{margin:auto;}
```